# Linear programming using Matrices in R

Tags: r, matrix

I need to solve a linear program in R where the variables are matrices.

More specifically, my optimizing function looks like this.

Max X(A+B)Y - x - y,

where X,Y,A,B are matrices and x,y are scalars. Solve for X,Y,x,y

Subject to bunch of constraints like any linear program

Is there a way to solve this in R?

I checked out linprog and limsolve packages in R. They solve linear programs of scalars.

Is there a way to do the same for matrices in R.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What have you tried already? And please provide a reproducible example up to the point where you are stuck.

Comment: The APIs present in linprog and limsolve, seem to accept only scalars. So, the question basically, are there other packages that can work in matrices in linear programs.

Comment: The easiest is probably to rewrite your problem using vectors rather than matrices:
take all the columns of `X` and `Y`, stack them on top of one another,
also add `x` and `y`, to form a single huge vector `Z`, 
and rewrite the objective using it.
But this will not help much: 
your problem is not linear, but quadratic (you have a product of `X` and `Y`).
The `quadprog` package can solve quadratic optimization problems, 
but only positive definite ones -- this one is at best positive semi-definite.

Comment: Did is more like bi-linear than quadratic. I can use quadprog, but is there a way to avoid breaking up the matrices. I think matlab would be able to handle this. Not sure about R.

Answer (score 0):

Googling for `R linear programming matrices` yielded a number of interesting links, of which the following might be interesting:

- [Simplex Method for Linear Programming Problems](http://astrostatistics.psu.edu/su07/R/html/boot/html/simplex.html), for the boot package.

Comment: This does not handle linear programs on matrices. You can just specify the coefficients of the objective function and constraints as vectors and matrices.